# Exponential smoothing on Excel for Mac?

Tags: excel, macos, charts, smoothing, excel-2016

Excel has an [exponential smoothing](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/exponential-smoothing.html). I have a graph I'd like to smooth, however the Mac version doesn't seem to have this feature.

[image]

Is there a way I can smooth the chart - either as a chart feature **or by using a formula in additional cells** to smooth the chart:?

Comment: You can read the post here [http://www.inventoryops.com/articles/exponential_smoothing.htm](http://www.inventoryops.com/articles/exponential_smoothing.htm).  Should answer your question.

Comment: @ross that seems to be focused on demand forecasting. I'm not doing any forecasting - I just have a series of values.

Comment: I believe the forecast would be your smoothed values; just don't have to go past the last value if you don't want to continue them.

Comment: @ross the way I read it is the smoothed values are the output of the function, and the demand and forecase are used as input.

Comment: "In Cell C4 we have our 1st exponential smoothing calculation  =(B3*$C1)+(B4*(1-$C1)) " - the forecast is the smoothed values from the demand line (which are your values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exponential smoothing can be done with a formula in MS Excel.

The first value(C3) would be equal to the first original value (B3).

The first smoothed value(C4), where the formula in the picture is highlighted would be equal to the value one above(C3) + alpha($C$1)* (next original value(B4) - previous smoothed(C3).

[image: smoothing]